# How to best code the following ? Is it doable ? Please see description

Tags: java, coding-style

As you will see below. I am writing a class named Property that can be bound to any Serializable type as evident from the class description.

Now the value in the property is auto bound to be of type `T` during compilation.

I want to implement a `Class getType()` method that should return the `Class` object of the value at runtime i.e.

```
Property<String> p = new Property<String>();

Class<String> cl = p.getType();
```

Here I expect cl to be String.class. Of course one way is:

```
return value == null ? null : value.getClass();
```

The issue is it won't reflect in the type returned and returns a raw type of `Class` object. 
Ideally I want it to be of type `Class<String>`

```
public class Property<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private T value = null ;
    private String name = null ;
    private boolean dirty = false ;
    private Entity parent = null ;

    public Class getType() {
        // Here I want to determine the type of T that this object is bound to ?
        return class; 
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value; 
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isDirty() {
        return dirty;
    }

    public void setDirty(boolean dirty) {
        this.dirty = dirty;
    }

    public Entity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Entity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3403987/626657

Comment: I think I am sticking to the option of 

    return value == null ? null : value.getClass(); 

as I noted in my question content. Though the type token approach shared by @Bohemian is an option, it will force client code to explicitly pass a type token. 

My codebase currently uses the other aspect pointed out by Stephen C i.e.

    public class IntegerProperty extends Property<Integer> {
        public Class getType() {
            returns Integer.class;
        }
    }

Its too much boiler plate with the extended property classes that I want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible the way you are doing it due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  One consequence is that this the type that is used to instantiate the type parameter cannot be directly determined at runtime.

Here are a couple of alternatives:

1)  Use getClass() to get the type of the *value* of the Property.

```
    public Class getType() {
        return value.getClass();
    }
```

2)  Explicitly pass the `Class` object for the actual type of T as constructor parameter.  Note that the generic typing means that you can't accidentally pass the wrong `Class` object

```
    private T value = null;
    private Class<T> type;

    public Property(Class<T> type) { this.type = type; }

    public Class<T> getType() { this.type; }
```

---

There is another approach (which probably won't work here from a design perspective) where you reify the Property classes; e.g.

```
    public class IntegerProperty extends Property<Integer> {
        public Class getType() {
            returns Integer.class;
        }
    }
```

There are clever variations of this where the subclass of the generic class in an anonymous class, and/or you access the type parameter via `getClass().getTypeParameters()`.  But note that the `getTypeParameters()` approach *only* works if you've extended a generic class with specific types for the type parameters.

Answer (score 6):

In short, you can't, because at runtime the type has been [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

But, you can do this (abbreviated to just the relevant code):

```
public class Property<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private T value = null;
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    // The constructor requires an instance of the Class<T>
    public Property(Class<T> clazz) { 
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    // Return a typed Class object
    public Class<T> getType() {     
         return clazz;  // echo back a typed Class object pass to the constructor
    }
```

The `Class<T>` object passed into the constructor is generally called a "type token".

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method

```
public Class<? extends T> getType() {
    return value == null ? null : value.getClass();
}
```

This will return the *runtime* type of `value`, and at compile-time provide as much information about the returned class as possible: it will be `T` or any subclass of `T`.

If you want to always return `Class<T>`, then you have to provide the class as a runtime argument, the way @Bohemian [describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967041/1468366) it. The type arguments of a generic class aren't available at runtime due to type erasure.